# How to install PHP-FPM on Clean Install of Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: server, 18.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

I am trying to install a LEMP stack on a clean install of Ubuntu Server 18.04.  I was able to get through installing everything except php-fpm.  It does not appear to be in the package repository even though every single instruction site (though it looks like everyone stole theirs from one site) on installing LEMP on 18.04 says to install it.  Any idea on how to get it installed or an alternate to php-fpm?

```
seafile@seafile:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 172 kB in 1s (139 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
sudo apt-get install php
php              php7.2-dev       php7.2-odbc      php7.2-snmp      php-cgi          php-gmp          php-pspell
php7.2           php7.2-gd        php7.2-opcache   php7.2-sqlite3   php-cli          php-ldap         php-recode
php7.2-cgi       php7.2-gmp       php7.2-pgsql     php7.2-tidy      php-common       php-mysql        php-snmp
php7.2-cli       php7.2-json      php7.2-pspell    php7.2-xml       php-curl         php-odbc         php-sqlite3
php7.2-common    php7.2-ldap      php7.2-readline  php7.2-xmlrpc    php-dev          php-pear         php-tidy
php7.2-curl      php7.2-mysql     php7.2-recode    php-all-dev      php-gd           php-pgsql        php-xmlrpc
sudo apt-get install php
```

Comment: Is `universe` enabled?

Comment: It appears that it is not enabled by default on the server edition at least.  Not surprised.  Just not used to that since I have been running the desktop version for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that it is not enabled by default on the server edition at least. Not surprised. Just not used to that since I have been running the desktop version for years.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```